# Where can I find the otrs-scheduler file?

Tags: linux, scheduler, otrs

Im trying to install [otrs](/questions/tagged/otrs) on a Debian system. I followed [these instructions](https://otrs.github.io/doc/manual/admin/3.3/en/html/manual-installation-of-otrs.html). It works well til the last step. But I can simply not find the file `scripts/otrs-scheduler-linux` which is referenced in the manual.

Where can I find the file?

Answer (score 1):

Starting OTRS 3.3.7, the scheduler file is removed because it was not running reliably on some systems. There is now a cron job which checks if the scheduler is running and if not, starts it.

The 3.3.x documentation was not updated to reflect this. So you can safely ignore this part of the installation.

Ref to the commit in which the file was removed: https://github.com/OTRS/otrs/commit/ee886feb2